# dpkg-reconfigure: what packages are supported?

Tags: dpkg, dialog, user-interface

`dpkg-reconfigure` gives a way to set options for installed packages in a "user-friendly" way (e.g. not editing files but selecting from dialogs).

How can I find out what package has such options? e.g. "`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`" does have it while "`dpkg-reconfigure nano`" does not.

What's the correct argument/package to add an additional `apt-mirror` via `dpkg-reconfigure` the "dialog-way"?

Comment: Whether `dpkg-reconfigure <package>` does anything worthwhile is up to the maintainer scripts involved (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst` usually).

Answer (score 7):

Dialogs in Debian package configuration scripts are typically handled by `debconf`; packages which support this will have matching `.config` and `.templates` files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` (*e.g.* `/var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata.config` and `/var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata.templates`). (This provides other benefits too, such as simple support for pre-seeding.)

Running `dpkg-reconfigure` runs a package’s `postinst` maintainer script in `configure` mode, so what happens when you do so really depends on what the maintainer provides. Most packages are designed to install silently so they don’t provide interactive configuration *via* `dpkg-reconfigure`.

Additional `apt` mirrors are configured by an installer module, not a `postinst` script, and as far as I know it isn’t available after installation.

Answer (score 3):

The following command give you the package list that can be used by `dpkg-reconfigure`. You need to install `debconf-utils` package first.

`$ debconf-get-selections | grep -v ^# | cut -f 2 | cut -d / -f 1 | sort | uniq`